# Displaying lists in Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am trying to create code where the user gets to input whether they want to add a number to a linked list. Every time they add a number, the new linked list gets displayed showing the collection of numbers. Here is the first class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true)
        {
            LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter command: ");
            String userInput = scan.nextLine();
            String [] parts = userInput.split(" ");
            String part1 = parts [0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
            int num = Integer.parseInt(part2);
            if (part1.equals("add"))
            {
                Set test = new Set();
                test.addNext(num);
                list.add(num);
                System.out.println(list.toString());

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the list print out like this:

```
Enter command: add 5
5
Enter command: add 8
8 5
Enter command: add 6
6 8 5
```

Comment: You are creating the list inside the loop. So, on every iteration, yoou have a new List instance. Move the list, the scanner and all other unnecessary fields outside the loop. Just keep the comparing and adding inside the loop.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I did what you suggested and the output now shows up like this: `[5,8,6]` shouldn't it be showing up as `[6,8,5]` since every time a node gets added it's to the front of the list?

Comment: No. You are adding to a `LinkedList` and then printing it out. List will be printed in the order you ahve inserted the elements

Comment: list.addFirst(num) will put new items in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Outside the `while` loop, because every iteration `list` is getting overridden by a brand new one, so naturally it will have only one element every time you print it.

It also seems you want to display the list in reverse order. Normally when you add elements, they are placed at the end of the list. You should use `addFirst()` to put them at the beginning and get your expected output.